# Having another class as a static property on a class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Read the example below*, but don't pay too much attention to the `EventEmitter` inheritance, please – it just shows the utility of the `class` syntax.

I realize that the example is not correct ES2015, since there no such thing as a `static class` statement.

What would be the most syntactically lean way to make something like this work in ES2015?

```
class App extends EventEmitter {
  addPage(name) {
    this[name] = new App.Page;
    this.emit("page-added");
  }

  static class Page extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this._paragraphs = [];
    }

    addParagraph(text) {
      this._paragraphs.push(text);
      this.emit("paragraph-added");
    }
  }
}
```

---

Should I just split it up and use a class expression, like below? Seems less elegant.

```
class App extends EventEmitter {
  addPage(name) {
    this[name] = new App.Page;
    this.emit("page-added");
  }
}

App.Page = class extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._paragraphs = [];
  }

  addParagraph(text) {
    this._paragraphs.push(text);
    this.emit("paragraph-added");
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you transpiling es6 to es5?
In babel you can achieve something close by enabling [es7.classProperties](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/)

Check, for example, this [snippet](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20App%20extends%20EventEmitter%20{%0A%20%20static%20Page%20%3D%20class%20extends%20EventEmitter%20{%0A%20%20}%0A})

Comment: That's cool, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I just split it up and use a class expression?

Yes, that's the way to go. If you insist on using a declaration, you'd have to make a `App.Page = Page` assignment afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your class created inside `addPage`. It will create the "abstraction" I suppose you're looking for, but you'll pay in performance (each `addPage` call will be slower.

```js
'use strict';

class EventEmitter {
  emit(s) {
    alert(s);
  }
}

class App extends EventEmitter {
  addPage(name) {
    class Page extends EventEmitter {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this._paragraphs = [];
      }

      addParagraph(text) {
        this._paragraphs.push(text);
        this.emit("paragraph-added");
      }
    }
    this[name] = new Page;
    this.emit("page-added");
  }
}

var app = new App;
app.addPage("myPage");
app.myPage.addParagraph("Some content");
```

Alternatively, have both classes defined in a module, and only export the `App` class thus preventing pollution of the global scope.